# Turn pngs to one ICO file

Tags: icons, image-conversion

How do i convert a series of pngs of 16,24, 32, 48, 64, 128 to one *.ico file

Answer (score 4):

You could try [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/).  It's free and it works great.  A few of the many features include:

> - **Batch processing for handling multiple files**
> - **Import image dialog, for creating icons from images**
> - Resolutions up to 256x256
> - Data types: 2, 16, 256, True Color, True Color + Alpha
> - Import / export images (transparency also) from bmp, jpg, gif, png, jp2
> - Create icon from an image with a single click

Assuming those images are the same image resized, you could also just import the largest size and use IcoFX to size the original down for the smaller sizes you want to include.

Of course, this won't help you if you're not using Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't free anymore. But the previous version should still work if you can find it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Paint.NET, you can try this plug-in:

http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewtopic.php?t=1152

Comment: Its not batch convert

Answer (score 2):

[**png2ico**](http://www.winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/) is a command-line tool to convert PNG files into icons.