# How can I combine several individual .ico files into a single file?

Tags: windows, icons

I was able to convert PNG files into ICO files (thanks to [Turn pngs to one ICO file](https://superuser.com/q/62771/7878) ), but now I would like to create an icon "bundle" similar to `system32.dll`, which contains several individual icons. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build a DLL that contains multiple icons as resources.  That can be done from Visual Studio via [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0%28VS.90%29.aspx).  Other Windows development tools that can create a DLL should be able to do the same thing.

This could even been done with the resource compiler (rc.exe) that is included in the Windows SDK and manually creating a [resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648007%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this will work as well.

http://convertico.org/Multi_Image_to_one_icon/

Comment: This uses a Flash-based file uploader, and does not work any more.

Comment: Are there any alternatives that don't use Flash?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there was a Java rewrite of *CombineIcons* called [*Icollator*](http://web.archive.org/web/20190811045850/http://www.the-vardemans.net/andrew/software/), although it still only supports up to 128x128 pixels.

Comment: could u elaborate your answer how icollator is usefull with respective to question

Comment: This doesn't work, the output file only contains one of the icons.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program could meet your requirement. It's GConvert:
https://www.gdgsoft.com/gconvert

But so far, this freeware only support 256x256 size. If you ok with that then you may wanna give it a shot.